# How can I get the day of the week for a given date in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, datepart

I want to retrieve day of the week from the given date.

For example the date is: `2015-01-28` then it has to return `Wednesday`

## My bad try:

```
select date_part('week',now()) as weekday;
```

The above script gives me only number of week but not the day of the week.

Comment: Check to_char(): http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try [`to_char()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-formatting.html):

```
select to_char(now(), 'Day')
```